# JavaMail crashes on Samsung Galaxy SIII

Tags: android, crash, jakarta-mail

I have the following implementation of JavaMail, which works fine on the Android 2.2 (Froyo) emulator (the project's target is set for version 17, latest). When I load it on a Galaxy SIII phone (Android 4.1.1 installed), the application crashes on the 'catch', by the LogCat indication; even the Toast inside the catch is not displayed. Any hints?
Here is the code:

```
/**
     * Send an Email with a file in attach (the file is located in SDCARD/mailattach/ directory)
     * @param emailAddress
     * @param emailObject
     * @param emailBody
     * @param attachedFile name
     */
    public static void sendEmail(String emailAddress, String emailSubject, String emailBody, String attachedFile)   {

        Email m = new Email(email_config.get("ACCOUNT_NAME"), email_config.get("ACCOUNT_PASSWORD")); 

        String[] toArr = { emailAddress };
        // Email server static initializations
        m.setHost(email_config.get("DEFAULT_SMTP_SERVER"));
        m.setPort(email_config.get("DEFAULT_SMTP_PORT"));
        if (email_config.get("SMTP_AUTHENTICATION") == "true")  {
            m.setSauth(true);
        } else {
            m.setSauth(false);
        }
        m.setSport(email_config.get("SOCKET_FACTORY_PORT"));
        if (email_config.get("DEBUG_MODE") == "true")   {
            m.setDebug(true);
        } else {
            m.setDebug(false);
        }       
        // Email transmitted parameters
        m.setTo(toArr); 
        m.setFrom(email_config.get("ACCOUNT_NAME")); 
        m.setSubject(emailSubject); 
        m.setBody(emailBody);

        String attachPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() +
                            File.separator + "mailattach" + File.separator + attachedFile;

        try {
            // set the attachment and send
            m.addAttachment(attachPath); 
            if(m.send()) { 
                Toast.makeText(context, "Email was sent successfully.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
            } else { 
                Toast.makeText(context, "Email was not sent.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
            } 
        } catch(Exception e) { 
          Toast.makeText(context, "Error sending the email: "+e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
        } 
    }
```

Comment: add an e.printStackTrace() and post the output pls. It seems the message is null

Comment: @matheszabi: did it (put it instead of the Toast inside the catch). The result is that the application doesn't crash, it works normally only that the email is not sent. I don't get any of the toasts inside the 'try'. On the Eclipse console there is no message printed (if it doesn't crash it means it doesn't go through the 'catch')

Comment: I think I know: NetworkOnMainThreadException. It seems that when targeting higher than version 9 I need to execute network operations in an AsyncTask ...

Comment: that will be the solution!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure to call the Networking in not the main thread, because Android 4 doesn't allow it.